# Reduce loops in function

Tags: php, regex, loops

How I can reduce the loops.
The attributes "data-type" and "data-id" and their values should be removed.
How I can reduce the loops.
The attributes "data-type" and "data-id" and their values should be removed.

`<a href="xyz" data-type="xyc" data-id="xpc"></a>`

```
function remove_url_attr($text) {
    $result = array();
    
    preg_match_all('|data-type="[^"]*"|U', $text, $result);
    foreach($result[0] as $html_tag) {
        $text = str_replace($html_tag, '', $text);
    }
    
    preg_match_all('|data-id="[^"]*"|U', $text, $result);
    foreach($result[0] as $html_tag) {
        $text = str_replace($html_tag, '', $text);
    }
    return $text;
}
```

Comment: `str_replace` can take arrays for first & second parameter.

Comment: (Btw., this sounds like you were removing custom data attributes from HTML code - why is the function called `remove_url_attr` then?)

Comment: You have an example, please?

Comment: For using `str_replace` with arrays? The _manual_ has.

Comment: What "whole content"? It will work on whatever `$text` value you pass into your function. _"An excample for that would be nice."_ - and so would be, if you made an actual effort first, before you keep asking for "examples." (If the examples in the manual are not enough for you to grasp how str_replace works with arrays - then what good are other "examples" going to do? You are not actually asking for an _example_ then, but for "rewrite my code" ...?)

Comment: Is not an custom data attribute. It was rendering from WordPress. 
For me, are this attributes on the url that I want to remove therefore the name of the function. Yes an excample for my code would be nice.

Comment: _"Is not an custom data attribute."_ - yes it it, because that's what those _are_ called - [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) _"For me, are this attributes on the url that I want to remove therefore the name of the function."_ - you are not working with URLs here, you are passing a variable containing _text_ (that appears to be HTML) into your function.

Comment: An example is always better for a beginner. It has nothing to do with straining. ;-)

Comment: Ok sorry for the misunderstanding. Yes, I pass a complete text in the function. That is right. In this text are a lot of urls. For these URLs I want to remove the attributes. Maybe I don't have to parse the whole text at all. I dont know. But the name of the function is also not very interesting. I just want to performantly remove the attributes.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve your problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Well as neither of the foreach loops are actually necessary as even if you were to pass multiple html elements containing the search terms the `str_replace()` will change ALL of them, I would remove both

```
function remove_url_attr($text) {
       
    preg_match_all('|data-type="[^"]*"|i', $text, $result);
    $text = str_replace($result[0], '', $text);
    
    preg_match_all('|data-id="[^"]*"|i', $text, $result);
    $text = str_replace($result[0], '', $text);

    return $text;
}

echo remove_url_attr('<a href="xyz" data-type="xyc" data-id="xpc"></a>');
```

RESULT

```
<a href="xyz"  ></a>
```

And if you pass more than one

```
echo remove_url_attr('<a href="xyz" data-type="xyc" data-id="xpc"></a> <a href="xyz" DATA-type="xyc" data-ID="xpc"></a>');
```

RESULT

```
<a href="xyz"  ></a> <a href="xyz"  ></a>
```

I also amended the Regex to make it case insensitive, in case the attributes are coded in uppper case or mixed case

Comment: Perhaps a look at the regular expression is also in order?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Probably, but I admit to being terrible with regex, so feel free to suggest

Comment: I think that just `data-type="[^"]*"` would do, without the other cases indicated by the `|` or. Oh, talking about being bad with regex, me too! I always avoid them as the plague they are.

Comment: @RiggsFolly thank you so much. That looks like better as my own code.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Ha that was fun, took your suggestion and also made the search case insensitive.

Comment: Regretably it's not correct yet. I always use [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rM2AfX/1) to check my expressions. It's very informative. As you can read in the "explanation", after you clicked the link, the expression doesn't do what you think it does. The expression you want is `/data-type="[^"]*"/gmi`.

Comment: Oh, thats what I was using :( Ahhh, the start and stop chars can be `/` but it still works with `|` but regex101 enforces a `/`

Comment: See https://3v4l.org/0spYU Didnt want to change the OP's code too much to add confusion

Comment: Yes, you're right. Oh, I clearly don't understand this. 

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Dont worry, we both learned a lttle something about regex's today. Thanks for setting me the challenge